# Проверка значений переменных на null или NaN и их замена на 0

Tags: javascript

Если несколько или одна переменная равна null или NaN, как сделать так, что ее значение перезаписалось на 0?

```
if (type_work_amount || type_work_amount2 || type_work_amount3 == null || NaN) {
    // код
}
```

Comment: Лучше сохраните данные в массив, вместо создания множества переменных :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 покажите пример как сделать массивом?

Comment: Я из вашего кода вообще не понимаю что происходит

Comment: $type_work_amount = 22;
$type_work_amount2 = null;
$type_work_amount3 = 99;

if ($type_work_amount === null) {
$type_work_amount = 0;
}
else if ($type_work_amount2 === null) {
  $type_work_amount2 = 0;
}
else if ($type_work_amount3 === null) {
  $type_work_amount3 = 0;
}

let sum = $type_work_amount + $type_work_amount2 + $type_work_amount3;
console.log(sum);

Comment: `[123, null, NaN].map(...)` - а внутри функция которая берёт первый аргумент - элемент массива, а в функции уже делаете проверку, если текущее значение невалидное (null или NaN), тогда возвращаете 0, в противоположном случае, возвращаете то же значение.

Answer (score 5):

Для проверки значений на **null**, **undefined**, **NaN** в большенстве случаев достаточно преобразовать значение к типу **boolean**, как это делается в операторе `if`.
Для явного преобразования можно воспользоваться функцией `Boolean(value)` или воспользоваться оператором **!!**(Двойное НЕ) `!!value`

> Стоит заметить, что 0 и пустая строка вернут false.

Если необходимо, что бы **0 и пустая строка были не false**, необходимо дополнительно реализовывать проверки.

#### Числа

Для чисел `(typeof value === 'number')` можно явно сравнить `value === 0`, однако стоит помнить, что **typeof NaN === 'number'**.
Проверить число, что оно является **NaN** можно при помощи встроенного метода чисел `Number.isNaN(value)`(Сокращенно `isNaN(value)`) - вернет true, если value это **NaN**
Для проверки числа на **Infinity** *(бесконечность - возникает при делении на 0)* есть встроенный метод `Number.isFinite(value)`(Сокращенно `isFinite(value)`) - вернет true если число конечно.

#### Строки

Для строки выполнить проверку `value === ''` или просто проверить на тип `typeof value === 'string'`

> Так же стоит помнить, что массив и объект всегда будут возвращать **true**, даже если они пустые.

#### Массивы

Для проверки массива достаточно проверить его длину. Если 0, то массив пустой
`value.length === 0 или if (!value.length) { массив заполнен } else { массив пуст }` 
Для проверки, что переменная является массивом, можно обратиться к встроенному методу массивов `Array.isArray(value)` - вернет true, если это массив.

#### Объекты

Для выполнения проверки, что объект пустой, можно воспользоваться встроенным методом объектов `Object.keys(values)`, который возвращает массив ключей.
Если длина полученного массива 0, значит объект пуст.

> Так как тип данных у массивов и объектов одинаковый и **typeof** вернет **'object'**, то для того что бы отличить массив от объекта, необходимо проверить, является ли он массивом через встроенный метод массива **Array.isArray(value)**

---

Относительно вашего примера, я бы пошел простым путем и создал бы функцию, которая будет возвращать 0 если значение **null** или **NaN** или само значение переменной, если это не так:

```js
let type_work_amount = 123;
let type_work_amount2 = null;
let type_work_amount3 = 3 / 'a';

console.log(type_work_amount, type_work_amount2, type_work_amount3);

function checkVariable(val) {
  if (!val) return 0
  return val;
}

console.log(checkVariable(type_work_amount));
console.log(checkVariable(type_work_amount2));
console.log(checkVariable(type_work_amount3));

//Если надо переопределить значение в переменной по условию, то можно присваивать переменной значение, которое возвращается из функции

type_work_amount = checkVariable(type_work_amount);
type_work_amount2 = checkVariable(type_work_amount2);
type_work_amount3 = checkVariable(type_work_amount3);

// Если надо что бы сработало одно из условий, то надо записать ваш IF вот так

if (!type_work_amount || !type_work_amount2 || !type_work_amount) {
  // Какой то ваш код
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> [123, null, NaN].map(...) - а внутри функция которая берёт первый аргумент - элемент массива, а в функции уже делаете проверку, если текущее значение невалидное (null или NaN), тогда возвращаете 0, в противоположном случае, возвращаете то же значение. - @NNL993

```js
let myArray = [null, 1, 2, "asdf", NaN];
myArray = myArray.map(el => (el === null || (typeof el == "number" && isNaN(el))) ? 0 : el)
console.log(myArray);
```