# Как убрать класс у кнопки

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть поле инпут и кнопка, если в инпуте ничего нету, то она серого цвета, а если добавить текст в инпут , то она загорается, не могу понять, как сделать так, что когда я вытираю текст полностью, кнопка опять становится серой ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sum: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    Temp() {
      console.log(this.sum)
      if (this.sum != null) return 'btnblack';
      if (this.sum == null) return 'btn';
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.inpblock {
  width: 372px;
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.summ {
  width: 180px;
  height: 48px; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
  color: #000000
}
.btn {
  width: 180px;
  height: 48px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.btnblack {
  width: 180px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  color: #FFC700;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
         <div class="inpblock">
            <input type="number" class="summ" v-model="sum">
            <button class="btn" :class="Temp()">Текст</button>
         </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Может так this.sum == ""

Comment: Пробовал, не работает

Comment: `if (this.sum) return 'btnblack'; return 'btn';` Если в this.sum что то есть будет возвращен класс **btnblack**, иначе вернется класс **btn**. Почитайте подробнее о [преобразовании данных к логическому типу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461372/#1461463)

Comment: <button :class="[sum ? 'btnblack':'btn']">Текст</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

собственно варианты в комментарии накидали

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sum: ''
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.inpblock {
  width: 372px;
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.summ {
  width: 180px;
  height: 48px; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.03em;
  color: #000000
}
.btn {
  width: 180px;
  height: 48px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 30px;
}
.btnblack {
  width: 180px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  color: #FFC700;
}
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    /* display: none; <- Crashes Chrome on hover */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0; /* <-- Apparently some margin are still there even though it's hidden */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
         <div class="inpblock">
            <input type="number" class="summ" v-model="sum">
            <button :class="[sum ? 'btn' : 'btnblack']">Текст</button>
         </div>
   </div>
```