# Автоматизация тестирования

Tags: javascript, тестирование, автоматизация

Задача: Автоматизировать процесс.
Код:

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    
async function testYaRu(){
    console.log('Запуск браузера');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    console.log('Создание новой вкладки в браузере');
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    console.log('Переход на страницу ya.ru');
    await page.goto('https://ya.ru/');

    console.log('Ввод текста "Автоматизация тестирования" в поисковую строку');
    const searchField = await page.$('#text');
    await searchField.type('Автоматизация тестирования');

    console.log('Клик в кнопку "Найти"');
    const searchButton = await page.$('.button[type=submit]');
    await searchButton.click();
    
    console.log('Ожидание перехода в страницу поисковых результатов');
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    // todo: напиши команду ожидания загрузки результата

    console.log('Получение элементов результата поиска');
    const result = await page.$('.serp-item');
    // todo: создай переменную result и положи в неё элемент поисковой выдачи

    console.log('Сравнение ОР и ФР');
    if (result.startsWith('.serp-item')) {
      console.log('Результаты поиска не найдены.');
    } else {
      console.log(`Результаты поиска отобразились.`)
    } 
    // todo:
    // напиши конструкцию if-else:
    // если результат null, выведи в консоль "Результаты поиска не найдены"
    // иначе, выведи в консоль "Результаты поиска отобразились" 
    
    console.log('Закрытие браузера');
    await browser.close();
}

testYaRu();
```

Проблема находится в части 'Сравнение ОР и ФР', не могу понять как переписать эту часть, понял что startsWith не подходит. Должно получиться так, что если результаты поиска отобразились, в консоль должно быть выведено "Результаты поиска отобразились", если нет "Результаты поиска не найдены" соответственно.

Comment: Что вообще возвращает `await page.$('.serp-item')`?

Comment: @SwaD по идее результаты поиска.

Comment: А по факту что приходит? Что бы выполнить в if проверку, надо же понимать, что сравнивать и с чем. Оттуда же может вернуться все что угодно

Comment: @SwaD вообще когда пытаюсь проверить, говорит что не может прочитать `await searchField.type('Автоматизация тестирования');` из-за type, хотя валидатор говорит что синтаксис верный.

Comment: А.... У вас же там даже пошаговая инструкция есть **если результат null**... [Как проверить на null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461372/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-null-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-nan-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-0/1461463?r=Saves_UserSavesList#1461463) можно почитать тут

Comment: селектор результата поиска `.serp-item`, нужно сравнить `result` и `null`