# Как написать функцию, которая будет записывать данные только тогда, когда они получены?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне надо, чтобы setIdPhoto записывал данные из likedImagesIds, но только тогда, когда там есть данные.

Вот что у меня есть:

```
const addIdPhoto = () => {
    if (likedImagesIds === null)
        setIdPhoto(likedImagesIds);
    }

addIdPhoto()
```

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите, указав условие `if (likedImagesIds === null)`. т.е. вызов **setIdPhoto** будет происходить только тогда, когда **likedImagesIds** -> **null**. Измение условие на **!==**

Comment: Или можно заменить `if (likedImagesIds === null)` на `if (likedImagesIds)`.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка значений переменных на null или NaN и их замена на 0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461372/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b0-null-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-nan-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-0)