# Как проверить значение ключа на тип данных

Tags: javascript

```js
const seats = {

    '2023-02-17': {
        '15:00': {
            'freeSeats': [
                '11','21','31','41','50'
            ],
            'format': true,
            'food': false
        },
    }
}
```

У меня есть объект `seats` в котором есть ключ `format`. Как проверить значение(`true`) ключа `format` на тип данных? Если значение ключа `format`(равняется типу данных NaN или undefined или null, выбрасывать ошибку `Неверный тип данных` )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof format`, `isNaN(format)` Почитайте вот тут про [проверки типов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461372/1461463#1461463)

Comment: @SwaD ну или `Number.isNaN`. (зависит от вашей задачи)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN`, `null` и `undefined` являются ложноподобными (falsy) значениями, поэтому они всегда соответствуют `false` в конструкции `if`, поэтому нужно проверить инвертированное значение `format`

```
const property = seats.some_nested_proterties.format
if(!property){
  throw new Error("Неверный тип данных")
}
```